# Reversing the strings from command line with threads in C - segmentation fault

Tags: c, unix, pthreads

I am new with threads.

I am trying to make a C program that reverses the string given from the command line and create a thread that does this for each one . When I run it gives me Segmentation fault .

Here is the code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

char* final[1000];

pthread_mutex_t *mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_t p[];

void *reverse(void* arg){
char* s[100];
char* temp;
int i;
strcpy(s,(char*)arg);
printf("S este %s",s);
for(i=0;i<=strlen(s)/2;i++){
    strcpy(temp,s[i]);
    strcpy(s[i],s[strlen(s)-i-1]);
    strcpy(s[strlen(s)-i-1],temp);
}

sleep(1);
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
strcat(final,s);
printf("Intermediar %s",s);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
return NULL;
} 



int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
int i;
int n = argc;
strcpy(final,"");
for(i=1;i<n-2;i++){
    pthread_create(&p[i],NULL,reverse,argv[i]);
}
for(i=1;i<n-2;i++){
    pthread_join(p[i],NULL);
}
//printf("Sirul final este %s",final);
return 0;
 }
```

Does anyone know a good site that could help me learn threads ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char* final[1000];
```

is an array (with 1000 elements) of pointer to char, you want an array of char:

```
char final[1000];
```

the same problem with this array:

```
char* s[100];
```

temp is declared as a pointer, but you use it as an array with size 1

declare the mutex without the * ,remove the initialization and add in main:

```
pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
```

you should also add a number to the array definition of pthread_t

Comment: Thank you ! I have declared a mutex variable with PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER before and had no problem . It worked as you said.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `temp`, so the call `strcpy(temp, s[i]);` causes undefined behavior.

Your treatment of `s` is also very confusing, the copying of `arg` (a string) into the memory used by `s` (an array of string pointers) is not valid. Just because you can cast away a warning doesn't mean you're doing something sensible.